# Yii2 Activerecord not saved before redirect and shown in "view"

Tags: events, yii2, xampp, yii2-active-records

Yii2 framework. When I save multiple ActiveRecords in AFTER_INSERT_EVENT of another ActiveRecord, the values in the database is not updated fast enough, so old values are shown when redirect to viewing the data.

To be more specific: Standard XAMPP environment with PHP 7.2.9. I have made a trait to make it easy to have extra attributes with history in model (either existing attributes or new attributes). The trait is used on ActiveRecord.

**Notice** the `sleep(5)` in function `TL_save`. This handled the problem, but it is not the correct solution. *How do I ensure all is updated before it is read again?* I want to avoid use locks on the row as that would require alteration of a table before it can be used. Is there a way around it? Transactions - I have tried it but perhaps not correct as it had no effect. A reload of the view page also solves the problem, but again: not very classy :-)

Also: Should I share this code on GitHub? I have not done so before and are not quite sure if it would be of any value to others really.

```
trait TimelineTrait
{   
    private $timelineConfig;

    public function timelineInit($config)
    {
        $std = [
            'attributes' => [],  // required
            '_oldAttributes'=>[],
            'datetime'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'validationRule'=>'safe',
            'table'=>$this->tableName(),
            'onlyDirty'=>true, // using !=, not !==
            'events'=>[
                self::EVENT_AFTER_INSERT=>[$this, 'TL_EventAfterInsert'],
                self::EVENT_AFTER_UPDATE=>[$this, 'TL_EventAfterUpdate'],
                self::EVENT_AFTER_FIND=>[$this, 'TL_EventAfterFind'],
                self::EVENT_AFTER_DELETE=>[$this, 'TL_EventAfterDelete'],
            ],
            'TimelineClass'=>Timeline::class,
            /*
                Must have the following attributes
                id integer primary key auto increment not null,
                table varchar(64) not null,
                table_id integer not null,
                attribute varchar(64) not null,
                datetime datetime not null
                value text (can be null)
            */
        ];
        $this->timelineConfig = array_replace_recursive($std, $config);
        foreach($this->timelineConfig["events"]??[] as $trigger=>$handler)
            $this->on($trigger, $handler);
    }

    public function __get($attr)
    {        
        $cfg = &$this->timelineConfig;
        if (in_array($attr, array_keys($cfg["attributes"])))
            return $cfg["attributes"][$attr];
        else
            return parent::__get($attr);
    }

    public function __set($attr, $val)
    {        
        $cfg = &$this->timelineConfig;        
        if (in_array($attr, array_keys($cfg["attributes"]))) {
            $cfg["attributes"][$attr] = $val;            
        } else
            parent::__set($attr, $val);
    }

    public function attributes()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::attributes(), $this->timelineConfig["attributes"]);
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $temp  = parent::rules();
        $temp[] = [array_keys($this->timelineConfig["attributes"]), $this->timelineConfig["validationRule"]];
        return $temp;
    }

    public function TL_EventAfterInsert($event) 
    {
        $this->TL_save($event, true);
    }

    public  function TL_EventAfterUpdate($event)
    {
        $this->TL_save($event, false);
    }

    private function TL_save($event, $insert) 
    {
        $cfg = &$this->timelineConfig;    
        if ($cfg["onlyDirty"]) 
            $cfg["_oldAttributes"] = $this->TL_attributesOnTime();        
       
        foreach($cfg["attributes"] as $attr=>$val) {
            $a = [
                'table'=>$cfg["table"], 
                'table_id'=>$this->id,
                'attribute'=>$attr,
                'datetime'=>$cfg["datetime"],
            ];

            if ($insert)
                $model=null;
            else 
                $model = Timeline::find()->where($a)->one();

            $isNew = empty($model); // this exact attribute does not exist on timeline already

            if ($isNew) 
                $model = new $cfg["TimelineClass"]($a);

            $model->value = $val;
           
            if (!$cfg["onlyDirty"] 
                || $cfg["onlyDirty"] && $model->value!=($cfg["_oldAttributes"][$attr]??\uniqid('force_true'))) {
                
                $ok = $model->save();
                if (!$ok) $this->addErrors($attr, $model->getErrorSummary());
            } 
        }
        sleep(5);        
    }

    public function TL_EventAfterFind($event)
    {
        $cfg = &$this->timelineConfig;
        $data = $this->TL_attributesOnTime();
        foreach($data as $attr=>$val)
            $cfg["attributes"][$attr] = $val;

        $cfg["_oldAttributes"] = $cfg["attributes"];
    }

    private function TL_attributesOnTime()
    {
        $cfg = &$this->timelineConfig;
        $timelineTable = $cfg["TimelineClass"]::tableName();        
        
        $sql = "SELECT t1.* FROM $timelineTable AS t1
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM $timelineTable WHERE `table`=:table AND table_id=:table_id AND datetime<=:datetime) AS t2
                ON (t1.table=t2.table and t1.table_id=t2.table_id and t1.datetime<t2.datetime AND t1.attribute=t2.attribute)
                WHERE t2.id IS NULL AND t1.datetime<:datetime AND t1.table=:table AND t1.table_id=:table_id
                ";
        $params = [
            'table'=>$cfg["table"],
            'table_id'=>$this->id,
            ':datetime'=>$cfg["datetime"],
        ];        
        $data = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql,$params)->queryAll();
        $data = ArrayHelper::map($data,'attribute','value');        
        return $data;
    }

    public function TL_EventAFterDelete($event) 
    {
        $cfg = &$this->timelineConfig;
        $cfg["TimelineClass"]::deleteAll([
            'table'=>$cfg["table"],
            'table_id'=>$event->sender->id
        ]);
    }

}
```

Example of it's use:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

class KeyTime extends Key
{
    use \app\behaviors\TimelineTrait;

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->timelineInit([
            'attributes'=>[
                // default values for attributes
                'keyid'=>'historic id', // this is existing attribute in Key model
                'label'=>'mylabel', // label and color does not exist in Key model
                'color'=>'red',
            ],   
        ]);
    }
}
```

The actionUpdate

```
   public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your action? I wonder if a redirect back to the page after the `ActiveRecord` save would work.

Comment: @Alex I have added it to the question. The KeyController::findModel sends a KeyTime instance back. I.e. the model is a KeyTime class.

Comment: I have also tried with transactions and ensured it is done correctly. The error still happened 1 out of 10 tries. Could it be hardware issues, such as writing is slowing than reading?

Comment: I have now tried many things. But not solved. I added `stop(\Yii::$app->db->createCommand('select * from timeline order by id desc limit 3')->queryAll());` at the end of `TL_save`. It throws an Exception with the last 3 records showing at this point - the values are correctly saved in database. So the problem is somewhere in the populating of the model. Help is still desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many "flashes" with `microtime(true)` on, I found the reason it worked sometimes with `sleep(1)`.

The answer is in `TL_attributesOnTime`. the last line in `$sql` was

```sql
WHERE t2.id IS NULL AND t1.datetime<:datetime AND t1.table=:table AND t1.table_id=:table_id
```

…but it should be…

```sql
WHERE t2.id IS NULL AND t1.datetime<=:datetime AND t1.table=:table AND t1.table_id=:table_id
```

Notice the **<** is changed to **<=** Otherwise when the record was saved in the same second as it was populated it would not be included.
Hope it can help somebody else.